# Invalid procedure call or argument (Error 5) when trying to put response from an API into a sheet

Tags: excel, vba, api

I'm trying to make an excel sheet to get the current temperature at different cities. I'm completely new to this API thing. I've managed to send a request and get information back. But when I'm trying to put the result in a sheet I'm not as successful. This is the code:

```
Sub VBAJson()

Dim xml_obj As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Set xml_obj = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

xml_obj.Open "GET", "the UrltoWeatherAPI", False


xml_obj.send


Dim weather As Object

Set weather = JsonConverter.ParseJson(xml_obj.responseText)



Dim Visa As Worksheet
Set Visa = Worksheets("Visa")   

Visa.Range("B2") = weather("city")("name")              'this line works
Visa.Range("B3") = weather("list")("0")("main")("temp") 'this gives me the error
                 '           ^      ^       ^
                 '      variant/ variant/  variant/
                 '      string   object/   string
                 '               dictionary


End Sub
```

The first line works and puts the city name in the cell B2, the second line gives me the error. "Invalid procedure call or argument (Error 5)" Anyone knows what might be the problem?

This is what the first few lines of the response looks like in a browser. These are the ones I'm using in the line that fails.

```
cod:                 "200"
message:             0
cnt:                 40,
list:
    0:
        dt:          1583442000,
        main:   
            temp:    274.27
```

In the end it looks like this:

```
city:
    id:              2697703
    name:            "Landvetter"
```

*edit*
I checked the contents of `weather` and it contained five items, one with the value `"list"`. When I checked that item it contained 40 items of the type "Variant/Object/Dictionary" None of them had a value.

Each of the 40 items contained 7 items, one of them was `"main"` which is the one I'm trying to use.

It seems like the 40 items are causing the problem. In the JSON response they just looks like "0", "1", "2" and so forth.

Comment: Hard (impossible) to tell why, without seeing the JSON you're processing. Try expanding `weather` in the *locals* toolwindow when debugging.

Comment: Added part of the response from the JSON. What it looks like in a browser.Does it help?

Comment: Also added info what `weather` contains and updated the main question.

Comment: Is "0" always the first key? These chained indexers are very hard to follow, but try going by numeric index instead of string key: `weather("list")(0)("main")("temp")`

Comment: Removing the quotes worked! But not  0, you had to start with 1. So `weather("list")(1)("main")("temp")`did work! Thank you!